# Time lapse animation

Tags: animation, matplotlib

I'm new to python, matplotlib, and animation.
I've not been able to find a clear, detailed description of
`animation.FuncAnimation(, , , , , , ......)`, so I've been trying to modifiy examples I've found.  What are all the allowed parameters for `FuncAnimation` in English?

I want to produce a graph of dots shown one at a time with a time about 1 second between appearances.

Here's my current code that just produces a continuous curve after a delay:

```
def init():
    line1.set_data([],[],'og')
    return line1,

def animate(x):
    x = np.linspace(0, 650, num=20, endpoint = True)  #start at 0, stop at 650, number of values
    y1 = (v0_y/v0_x)*x - (g/2)*(x/v0_x)**2
    line1.set_data(x, y1)
    time.sleep(1)
    return line1,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=100, interval=3000, blit=True)
```

All suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the documentation of `FuncAnimation` [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation), and this is an example code that does what you want:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np

xs = np.linspace(0, 650, num=20, endpoint = True)
ys = np.random.rand(20)

fig = plt.figure()
line1, = plt.plot([],[],'og')

plt.gca().set_xlim(0,650)

def init():
    return line1,

def animate(i):

    line1.set_data(xs[:i], ys[:i])
    return line1,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1000, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Output window:

[image]

Comment: I very much appreciate the response.  However, when I run this example, it only plots 2 points.   Each time it is run it only plots two different points.   I think it should plot 20 random points. I still do not understand animation.FuncAnimation - the referenced doc is way too terse!

Comment: I've just copy-pasted the code today and after running I got the Image posted (just added) on the answer. The points show one by one till the last.